# How do I wrap a single command in single quotes

Tags: php, bash, laravel-5

Here Ive a set of commands, what I'm trying to do is enter into a particular folder, ie., $path, which I'm passing from PHP script. Then create a file there called baber.txt and write a $key, which is also passed from PHP script. Next step ie., fetching the url with curl, I'm not getting the response of that particlar command, because all the commands are wrapped inside the double quotes. When I try to wrap all the commands inside single qotes, the first command itself fails, verything I've tried is giving an error, anyone have an idea on how to quote these commands..

```
               "cd $path
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    touch laber.txt
                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                        echo $key >> laber.txt
                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then",
                            'response=$(curl --head -s -u 98ur5t9@:9@98ur5t GET "http://$url/laber.tx")
                            if [[ $response =~ "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]]; then
                                echo ok;
                            else
                                echo url NOT ok;
                            fi',
                        "else
                            echo 2;
                        fi
                    else
                        echo 3;
                    fi
                else
                    echo 4;
                fi"
```

Comment: there are problems with your script beyond embedding it in php. for example, `[[ echo "$response"=~ 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' ]]` should not have the `echo` and there should be a space between the `"` and the `=`.

Comment: @webb corrcted those mistakes, Still no luck..

Comment: can you remove the quotes around `"http://$url/laber.tx"`without breaking something (typically $url will not contain spaces?) And replace those `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK"` by single quotes? Then you could have the whole code inside the double quotes and avoid breaking it with , and different quoting styles

Comment: @StefanHegny I've removed the quote, and getting this usual error exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: response'

Comment: where is `$url` defined? it's in single-quotes, so php won't interpolate it for you... a good first step would be to make an example that works in bash, then try to get that to work in php.

Comment: It is working in bash, this qoutes are making the mess in php ..

Answer (score 0):

i think this is your best bet (assuming that `$url` is set previously in your bash code. if it's a php var, then you'll need to replace `$url` with `'.$url.'`):

```
'cd '.$path.'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    touch laber.txt
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo '.$key.' >> laber.txt
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            response=$(curl --head -s -u 98ur5t9@:9@98ur5t GET "http://$url/laber.tx")
            if [[ "$response" =~ "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]]; then
                echo ok
            else
                echo url NOT ok
            fi
        else
            echo 2
        fi
    else
        echo 3
    fi
else
    echo 4
fi';
```

ps: url is intentionally .tx not .txt?